# Azure User assigned managed identities and Blob Storage exceptions

Tags: azure, azure-storage, blazor-server-side, visual-studio-2022, azure-managed-identity

I am working on a Blazor Server application. The app uses Azure AD for auth, and Blob Storage account. I want to use User assigned managed identities to get rid of having keys inside appsetting.json.

I created the User assigned managed identities and Add to my Azure App Service and Storage Account. I have the role of Storage Account Contributor and Storage Blob Data Contributor.

I am using Visual Studio 2022 and signed in with the same name and privileges that I am logged in into my Azure.

I get the error when I run my app locally on my VS2022.

Blew is the code :

```html
string accountName = "accountname";
            string containerName = "test";
            string containerEndPoint = string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}",
                accountName, containerName);

            string userAssignedClientId = "some id copy pasted from Azure";

            BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient
                                                  (new Uri(containerEndPoint),
                                                  new DefaultAzureCredential(
                                                      new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions() 
                                                      { ManagedIdentityClientId = userAssignedClientId}
                                                   ));

            try
            {
                await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
                string blobContents = "sending text from my VS2022";
                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(blobContents);

                using(MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
                {
                    await containerClient.UploadBlobAsync("testing.txt", stream);
                }
            }
            catch(System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"something went wrong {ex.Message}");
                logger.LogError("Hello From DPUBot Blazor Server App Log4Net Test");
                logger.LogTrace(ex.Message);
            }
```

When I run my app locally, it throws an exception:

```html
This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:some id
Time:2022-07-29T19:23:30.3826188Z
Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.)
ErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

Content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationPermissionMismatch</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:some id
Time:2022-07-29T19:23:30.3826188Z</Message></Error>

Headers:
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: some id
x-ms-client-request-id: some id
x-ms-version: 2021-06-08
x-ms-error-code: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
Date: Fri, 29 Jul 2022 19:23:29 GMT
Content-Length: 279
Content-Type: application/xml
```

Do you have any ideas why I am getting this Exception? I used the tutorial that Microsoft uses and mine does not work.

Thank you all.

Comment: Do you get the error when you run it locally or only when the app is running in Azure? Can you share the code of how you are connecting to Azure Storage?

Comment: So does your account have `Storage Blob Data Contributor` role ?

Comment: Yes, I have that role of Storage Account Contributor and Storage Blob Data Contributor.